# How to Address/Fix Gap Between Door Leaf and Jamb?

Tags: doors, door-frame, jamb

My exterior door (36"wide, 96" tall, made of metal and engineered materials, wood jamb/sides) has developed a very noticeable gap to the outside world.  This is not a weatherstrip issue, although new/more.oversized weatherstripping might reduce the problem some, as might jimmying with the hinges a bit as the gap between door and jamb on hinge side is small/normal and mostly consistent, with maybe 1-2 mm wider at top than at bottom.  Issue has more to do with the fact that the door jamb has widened at bottom over time due to a bit of slab/foundation movement by about 5-6 mm (~.2 inches) or so.  As you can see from the attached pic, it is pretty obvious and clearly leaking hot/cold air during the year.

BTW, when I lock the door (shoot the bolts) a lot of this daylight/gap goes away as the door is pushed/drawn in whatever direction by the bolts going into the striker plate hole.  The pic below shows the gap at it's worst.

So, as mentioned, I can try new/more weatherstripping or hinge adjustments, but this gap seems a little more than either of those would be able to sufficiently address since the outer "lip" of the jamb itself that the weather stripping sits on has moved away from the edge of door.  Someone has suggested adding another 1/8" or 1/4" strip of "jamb" to the outside, effectively providing more space to put weatherstripping on; this seems like a good approach to me, but I thought I'd check here for opinions and to ask what best way to go about that is?  It seems easy to mess up, i.e. look bad or draw the eye.

<sub>Click for full size</sub>
[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Is the door jamb/stop wood or part of a metal door frame?  If wood will probably be able to pull it off and adjust placement to better match the closed door.  A picture of the door jamb will help.

Comment: @crip659, Door jamb is (painted) wood, and I've edited/added pics requested to OP.

Answer (score 3):

The solve depends on how ambitious you are. The best thing (IMO) would be to pull the casing off and shim the door jamb back into its proper position. Of course, this entails significant work and then repainting and all that. The *next best* thing (IMO) would be to extend the door stop out with a thin strip of wood, to cover the gap. Weatherstrip will be beneficial (IMO) with either strategy, as I seen none in use at present.

Comment: Thanks...I'll check costs and etc. with a handyman on the 1st (full-blown) fix you've outlined.  I've been mulling the 2nd one in your answer (even part of my OP) for a couple of weeks, now...seems straight-forward enough, even if a bit of a hack/kludge.  There >>is<< weatherstripping there...it's the black line running down the inside of the jamb in 2nd pic.  It is really good stuff...way better than that Frost King cr@p which seems to be only thing anyone can find in Lowes Depot now, but it is 25 years old and showing its age.

Comment: I see weatherstripping on the door stop in the 2nd pic, but it looks to me like the door is simply too small (or the jamb is just too wide).  I'm actually kinda surprised the door actually latches with that much of a gap to the strike plates.